# angular-translate not working on templates

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I'm trying to make use of angular-translate for localization, but I'm having an issue where it only works on the home page. After clicking on a link, the next page isn't translated at all.

The weird thing is that the navbar translations(located on index.html) still translate properly, but the content in the ngview isn't translated. The controller for the other page is currently empty.

[image]

```
-App.js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'pascalprecht.translate']);

myApp.config(
function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
  when('/signup', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/signup.html',
        controller: 'SignUpControllers'
    }).
  otherwise({
        templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
    });
})
.config(function ($translateProvider) {
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
    prefix: '/languages/',
    suffix: '.json'
});
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
});
```

Another thing I noticed is that the default page content on home.html IS translated properly, but any other page doesn't get translated properly.

[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/nZMIJe0RwJ2dTe20Vzcg?p=preview) - example works correctly

Comment: can you set a plunkr to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: @DanPantry I added a plunker showing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your set up which is preventing the route that is not being translated from loading correctly. From your plunkr:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'SignUpControllers' is not a function, got undefined
```

This would indicate that you haven't set up `SignUpControllers` properly in your module configuration. Indeed, you haven't actually defined that controller in your plunker.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't quiet finished with the plunker before posting the link. I didn't expect such a quick reply! The controller is defined, but the translation still don't appear. However, not declaring a controller, such as the about page lets the translation work.

Comment: I got it. I wasn't declaring the controller properly, instead I was creating a new module. Updated the plunkr with correct code, so it all seems to be working now.